# Ninject StandardKernel GetProvider

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ninject

I'm trying to get the FullName of the class that's going to implement the interface. I use a `StandardKernel`

```
Kernel = new StandardKernel();
```

But I can't seem to get the info I want because

```
Kernel.GetBindings(type).FirstOrDefault().GetProvider() //ignore the pos. null for this example
```

`GetProvider()` Requires an `IContext` and I can't figure out where to get it from...

Answer (score 2):

Bit strange solution but worked for me in a simple cases:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IEnumerable>().To<Array>();
var kernelTarget = kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IEnumerable)).First ().ProviderCallback.Target;
var typeName = kernelTarget.GetType().GetField("prototype").GetValue(kernelTarget).ToString();
```